# Возникает ошибка 422 в fetch запросе в API на FASTAPI

Tags: javascript, fetch, fastapi

```
async function test() { 
   const url = 'работающая api';
   var mydata = { username: 'test123', password: 'test123' };
   var data = new FormData();
   data.append("json", JSON.stringify(mydata)); try {   const response = await fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST', 
   body: data, 
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log('Успех:', JSON.stringify(json));
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Ошибка:', error);
}
}
test().then((data)=>console.log(data))
```

postman: работает
[image: Postman]

/login на FastApi
[image: FastApi]

message error 422:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","username"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"},{"loc":["body","password"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

Серверный код

```
from fastapi.param_functions import Depends
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm

@registr_router.post("/login")
async def login(request: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()) -> dict:
   user = await registr.check_auth(request.username)
   if not user:
       raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail='User doesnt exist')
   if not verify_password(request.password, user['password']):
       raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Incorrect password")
   access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
   access_token = create_access_token(
       data={"sub": request.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
   )
   return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

oauth.py

```
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer

from app.auth.JWTtoken import verify_token


oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl='login')


async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)) -> str:
   credentails_exception = HTTPException(
       status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
       detail="Invalid authentication credentials",
       headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
   )
   return verify_token(token, credentails_exception)
```

Comment: Приведите пример серверного кода

Comment: Добавил пример.

Answer (score 0):

А вы уверенны, что `data.append("json", JSON.stringify(mydata))` выполняет то, что вы ожидаете?

Судя по сообщению ошибки, вы не передаете требуемые ключи в запросе

Нужно передать:

```
{
 'username': 'test123',
 'password': 'test123',
}
```

А вы передаете:

```
{
  'json': "{'username': 'test123', 'password': 'test123'}"
}
```

Сделайте так:

```
data.append("username", 'test123');
data.append("password", 'test123');
```

Comment: Тоже самое, проблема в headers, если без них передать, как вы сказали, все работает, но у меня возникает вопрос, что не так с ними?